# Make part of text dark when overlapping SVG shape

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, webkit

I have an H1 tag and want to make everything in the H1 tag that's overlapping my SVG shape dark like the image below. I considered just using an image, but the problem is that the text will be moving across the webpage so different parts of the H1 will overlap every time. I have also tried to use `mix-blend-mode: difference;` but i am not satisfied with the result[image]

The SVG path is too long to include here, but its similar to what's shown below. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Interesting (and shockingly common) problem. One of the best tricks I've seen to accomplish this is to have two instances of your text and create a "clipping mask" for each with inverted colors. It's not a perfect or elegant solution, but when all else fails, I have seen it work.

Comment: Try this [MDN Web Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

Comment: Ok, i will give this a try.